# Asp.Net Core Jwt access_token signing and encryption

Tags: encryption, asp.net-core-3.1, jwt, c#-8.0

TLDR; I'm trying to understand ***HOW*** the Jwt Middleware is able to pick up that I've signed and encrypted my token using the following signature/encryption scheme:

```
SigningCredentials TokenSigningKey = new SigningCredentials( "MySignatureSecurityKey", SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512);
EncryptingCredentials TokenEncryptingKey = new EncryptingCredentials( "MyEncryptionSecurityKey", JwtConstants.DirectKeyUseAlg, SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256CbcHmacSha512 );
```

In my `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices` method, I've configured my service to `AddAuthentication(options).AddJwtBearer:`

```
services.AddAuthentication( options =>
{
    ...
} )
.AddJwtBearer( options =>
{
    ...
    options.TokenValidationParameters =
        new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ...
            IssuerSigningKey = "MySignatureSecurityKey"
            TokenDecryptionKey = "MyEncryptionSecurityKey"
            ...
        };
} );
```

Nowhere did I need to configure the signature/encryption scheme, I just passed it the keys to use. I only configure the signature/encryption scheme when I actually sign/encrypt the token and there's no connect between that and the middleware.

Additionally, any advice regarding whether this is correctly defined or where to find documentation on what the current best practice configuration is would be highly appreciated:

```
SigningCredentials TokenSigningKey = new SigningCredentials( "MySignatureSecurityKey", SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512);
EncryptingCredentials TokenEncryptingKey = new EncryptingCredentials( "MyEncryptionSecurityKey", JwtConstants.DirectKeyUseAlg, SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256CbcHmacSha512 );
```

I've had to cobble this together from various bits and pieces all over the net as the documentation is very crude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my goodness, can't believe I missed it.  I must have decoded the access_token incorrectly when I checked it after I applied encryption because I just did it again and the answer was staring me straight in the face.

The first part of the access_token looks like this:
`eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0..`
decoded, it looks like this:
{"alg":"dir","enc":"A256CBC-HS512","typ":"JWT"}

Total Homer Simpson moment XS

So to answer the question:
The Jwt middleware takes the encrypted token (it gets presented as a `bearer token`) and by decoding the first part (see above), it can see that the following:

1. Algorithm = "dir" / DirectKeyUse
2. Encryption = "A256CBC-HS512" / Aes256CbcHmacSha512

The middleware knows to handle it because the "typ" is "JWT".

Hopefully this will assist someone else too.